# Combination of match and lapply in R

Tags: r, match, lapply

Here is my problem.

I have 8 * 3 dataframes. 8 for the years (2005 to 2012) and for each year I have three data frames corresponding to ecology, flowerdistrib and location. The names of the csv files are based on the same typology (flowerdistrib_2005.csv, ecology_2005.csv, ...)

I would like to constitute for each year a data frame which contains all the columns of the "flowerdistrib" file and part of the "ecology" and "location" ones.

I imported all of them thanks to this script:

```
listflower = list.files(path = "C:/Directory/.../", pattern = "flowerdistrib_")

for (i in listflower) {
filepath1 <- file.path("C:/Directory/.../",paste(i))
assign(i,read.csv(filepath1, sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE))
}
```

Same for ecology and location.

Then I want to do a vlookup for each year with the three files with some specific columns.
In each year, the csv files ecology, location and flowerdistrib have a column named "idp" in common.

I know how to do for one year. I use the following script:

2005 example, extraction of the column named "xl93" present in the file location_2005.csv:

```
flowerdistrib_2005[, "xl93"] = location_2005$"xl93"[match(flowerdistrib_2005$"idp", location_2005$"idp")]
```

But I don't know how to proceed to do this once for all the years. I was thinking of using a for loop combined with the lapply function but I don't handle it very well as i am a R beginner.

I would appreciate any and all help.

Thanks a lot.

PS: I am not an english native, apologies for the possible misunderstandings and probably language mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a re-organization of your read.csv proceedure, but you could use something like the script below to do what you need to do. It would create a list `data`, which contains all dataframes for the years specified. You can also potentially combine all those data frames into one, if the input tables all have the very same structure.

Hope this helps, not sure if the code below works if you copy paste it and update the paths, but something very similar to this could work for you hopefully.

```
# Prepare empty list
data <- list()

# Loop through all years
for(year in 2005:2012){

    # Load data for this year
    flowers <- read.csv(paste('C:/Directory/.../a/flowerdistrib_', year, '.csv', sep=''), sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE)
    ecology <- read.csv(paste('C:/Directory/.../a/ecology_', year, '.csv', sep=''), sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE)
    location <- read.csv(paste('C:/Directory/.../a/location_', year, '.csv', sep=''), sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE)

    # Merge data for this specific year, using idp as identifier    
    all <- merge(flowers, ecology, by = "idp", all = TRUE)
    all <- merge(all, location, by = "idp", all = TRUE)

    # Add a year column with constant year value to data
    all$year <- year

    # Drop unused columns
    dropnames = c('column_x', 'column_y')
    all <- all[,!(names(all) %in% dropnames)]

    # Or alternatively, only keep wanted columns
    keepnames = c('idp', 'year', 'column_z', 'column_v')
    all <- all[keepnames]

    # Append data to list
    data[[as.character(year)]] <- all
}

# At this point, data should be a list of dataframes with all data for each year
# so this should print the summary of the data for 2007
summary(data[['2007']])

# If all years have the very same column structure,
# you can use use rbind to combine all years into one big dataframe
data <- do.call(rbind, data)

# This would summarize the data frame with all data combined
summary(data)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, it works perfectly. However, I have a quick question at the rbind step (to combine all years into one data frame). Indeed, if all the csv files have the same structure, the 2009 to 2012 csv files have some columns that the others don't have. I'd like to delete these supplementary columns to do the rbind step. Where does it go in the script and how to write it properly ? Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked! I added two options to my answer: either, create a list of columns to drop, or specify a list of columns to keep. Both should work, but the "keep" version would make explicit which rows to keep, and thus make clear that all data frames in `data` have identical rows and which ones.

Comment: Thank you very much ! The "drop" version works well. Unfortunately, there is a problem with the syntax all[keepnames] in the "keep" version, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Well if the "drop" works, then the problem seems to be solved. If that is the case, could you maybe mark this answer as the accepted one?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version using some functional programming concepts. First, we write a function `read_and_merge` that accepts a year as an argument, constructs a list of files for the year, reads them into `data_` which is a list consisting of three files. The final trick is to use the `Reduce` function which recursively merges the three data frames. I am assuming that the only common column is `idp`.

```
read_and_merge <- function(year, mydir = "C:/Directory/.../a/"){
  files_ = list.files(mydir, pattern = paste("*_", year, ".csv"))
  data_ = lapply(files_, read.csv, sep = ";", dec = ",", header = TRUE)
  Reduce('merge', data_)
}
```

The second step is to create a list of the years and use `lapply` to create datasets for each year.

```
mydata = lapply(2005:2012, read_and_merge)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It seems very efficient but I have some problems to apply it correctly. So, when I do : read_and_merge <- function(year, mydir = "C:/Dir/.../"){
  flower_ = list.files(mydir, pattern = paste("flower_", year, ".csv"))
  ecology_ = list.files(mydir, pattern = paste("ecology_", year, ".csv"))  
  location_ = list.files(mydir, pattern = paste("location_", year, ".csv"))  
  data_ = lapply(c(flower_, ecology_, location_), read.csv, sep = ";", dec = ",", header = TRUE)
  Reduce('merge', data_)
}

mydata = lapply(2005:2012, read_and_merge) and then head(mydata)

Comment: (sorry not space enough in the precedent post), R says: [[1]] NULL ... [[8]] NULL. I confirm that the only common cloumn is idp.

Comment: So does `mydata` contain the output you are looking for?

Comment: No, `mydata` contains 8 NULL values. NB: the script I used `read_and_merge <- function(year, mydir = "C:/Dir/.../"){ 
  flower_ = list.files(mydir, pattern = paste("flower_", year, ".csv"))
  ecology_ = list.files(mydir, pattern = paste("ecology_", year, ".csv"))  
  location_ = list.files(mydir, pattern = paste("location_", year, ".csv"))  
  data_ = lapply(c(flower_, ecology_, location_), read.csv, sep = ";", dec = ",", header = TRUE)
  Reduce('merge', data_)
}

mydata = lapply(2005:2012, read_and_merge) `